# Button not being displayed in window

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to add three buttons to a window. I've tried it without classing and it works fine. But when I add it in a class, it only show me an empty window. What am I doing wrong?

PS: I'm still in the process of learning the ropes in python.

```
from tkinter import filedialog,Button,Frame,Tk

class Textify:

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.initializeOutlineFrame

    def initializeOutlineFrame(self):
        self.convertImageButton = Button(master,text="Convert Image",command=self.browseIMG,width=80,height=30)
        self.convertImageButton.pack()
        self.convertPdfButton = Button(master,text="Convert pdf",command=self.browsePDF)
        self.convertPdfButton.pack()
        self.batchConvertButton = Button(master,text="Convert multiple files",command=self.browseAllFiles)
        self.batchConvertButton.pack()

    def browsePDF(self):
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",
        title = "Select a File",filetypes = (("pdf files","*.pdf*"),("all files", "*.*")))

    def browseIMG(self):
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",
        title = "Select a File",filetypes = (("jpg files","*.JPG*"),("png files","*.PNG*")))

    def browseAllFiles(self):
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",
        title = "Select files",filetypes = (("jpg files","*.JPG*"),("png files","*.PNG*"),("pdf files","*.pdf*")))


window = Tk()
window.title("Textify")
window.geometry("450x450")
app = Textify(window)
window.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: `self.initializeOutlineFrame` does nothing; you've merely mentioned the name of the method, not called it.  Try `self.initializeOutlineFrame()`.

Comment: tried that. still did nothing

Comment: Also need to change the `master` to `self.master` in the function `initializeOutlineFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `initializeOutlineFrame()` instead of `initializeOutlineFrame`.
2. In the `def initializeOutlineFrame(self, master)`, change all `master` into `self.master`.
3. Be careful ! `width=80,height=30` doesn't define the size in pixels, but in characters. So at this stade, if you run the code, you are going to see a giant button and not the others buttons. Remove or change the values, for example like `width=17,height=3`.

**[optional]** You can grid buttons instead of pack for adding space around. It looks better:

```
def initializeOutlineFrame(self):

    self.convertImageButton = Button(self.master, text="Convert Image", \
    command=self.browseIMG, width=17, height=3)
    self.convertImageButton.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10)

    self.convertPdfButton = Button(self.master, text="Convert pdf", \
    command=self.browsePDF, width=17, height=3)
    self.convertPdfButton.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=10, pady=10)

    self.batchConvertButton = Button(self.master, text="Convert multiple files", \
    command=self.browseAllFiles, width=17, height=3)
    self.batchConvertButton.grid(column=2, row=0, padx=10, pady=10)
```